# How to sort an array of dictionary with a searchbar

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to display only the cells with the same title as the searchbar text. I thought that I had have a few methodes, but none of them seem to work.

Methode 1:

```
func Search() {
    Aanbiedingen_bieren_Filter = Aanbiedingen_bieren_Filter.filter {SearchBar.text!.lowercased() == $0.Title.lowercased() }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Methode 2:

```
func Search() {
    for Json in Aanbiedingen_bieren_Filter {
          let Naam = Json.Title.lowercased()
          if SearchBar.text!.lowercased().contains(Naam) {
               Aanbiedingen_bieren_Filter.append(Json)
          }
     }
     tableView.reloadData
}
```

When Searchbar text change run Search()

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ SearchBar: UISearchBar) {
    Search()
}

func searchBar(_ SearchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    Search()
}
```

Struct:

```
struct SheetJS: Codable {
    var SheetJS: [Aanbiedingen_bier]

    init(SheetJS: [Aanbiedingen_bier]) {
        self.SheetJS = SheetJS
    }
}

struct Aanbiedingen_bier: Codable {
    let Title: String

    init(Title: String) {
        self.Title = Title     
    }
}
```

Json:

```
"SheetJS": [
    {
      "Logo_Image": "Grolsch Premium Pilsener"
     },//Some more data
  ]
```

When I run this code it will give me an empty `Aanbiedingen_bier_Filter` back. I am not sure why this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of your tests is what you want:

```
SearchBar.text!.lowercased().contains(Naam)

SearchBar.text!.lowercased() == $0.Title.lowercased
```

What you want to know is whether the title contains the search text, not the other way round or whether they are identical (very unlikely).